# how to send 2 PoJos in the POST request body using jersey?

Tags: java, rest, http, gradle, jersey

I want to send a Pojo with a POST using jersey.

I understand there are 2 versions of Jersey: 1... and 2...

I'm adding code to an existing project which uses:

```
compile('com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.19')
compile('com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.19')
compile group:  'org.codehaus.jackson', name:'jackson-jaxrs', version: '1.1.1'
```

I have tried few ways to send 2 PoJos in the POST request body.

but none of them worked.

```
public void acquireDevice1(Device device, int port) throws InvalidArgumentException {

    WebResource webResource = this.client.resource(this.rootUri);
    webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Device.class, device)
            .post(Integer.class, port);

}
```

and

```
@Override
public void acquireDevice(Device device, int port) throws InvalidArgumentException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String deviceString = null;
    try {
        deviceString = mapper.writeValueAsString(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(rootUri + "/devices/acquireDevice/");

    ClientResponse response = webResource
            .type("application/json")
            .post(ClientResponse.class, deviceString);

    if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

should I wrap it all in a `map<string,object>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Post operations are not composable, each one maps to a web request,  to support your use case you need to combine the two Pojos into a single pojo using a third pojo that combines them, i.e. DeviceWithPort (or as you suggested a map - though that is less readable, or a tuple).

Jersey1/2 don't have any differences in this respect, as mentioned above this is part of HTTP, so no client will be likely to do anything different.